# Why hasn't the third novel in the Moonlit Bay trillogy been written and published yet?

Tags: dean-koontz, moonlit-bay

For a long time I've known there would be a final book in the [Moonlit Bay trilogy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moonlight_Bay_Trilogy) (largely due to the ending of the second book). However it'd been over twenty years since *Seize the Night* was written. What is delaying the writing and publication of the third book?

Koontz is quoted as saying he's been writing it since the early 2000s:

> "I'm half way through Ride the Storm, the third Christopher Snow story, but another book will appear between False Memory and Ride."

But *Ride the Storm* hasn't materialised, despite *False Memory* being published in 1999.

Comment: I realise the answer to this question is in the linked wikipage, if you click through to the *Ride the Storm* page, however I have wanted to ask this question since before that information was available. I came across some of the information to answer it separately but the couldn't find it again until now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The main impediment to the series is that [Koontz no longer hold the rights to this series.](https://twitter.com/deankoontz/status/1205515267650007040)

[image: screenshot of a twitter post by dean koontz]

> I like the 2nd Chris Snow novel. My publisher didn't. Maybe one day I'll get the rights back to the first 2 and be able to finish the third.

The Wikipedia page for [Ride the Storm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ride_the_Storm_(novel)) links to a [Goodreads post](https://www.goodreads.com/questions/1768737-will-you-ever-go-back-to-moonlight-bay-and) that states:

> The book was well reviewed and popular with readers, but I was given to understand that I had better write a few other books before forcing the issue with the third in the trilogy, or perhaps find yet another publisher.

Further more on the rights to the first two books:

> the first two books are locked up there, it has seemed too difficult to publish and promote the third book elsewhere.

However there is hope:

> maybe I can write one more Chris Snow not as the third in the trilogy, but as a nice fat standalone that reprises the background of the first two in a fresh way and carries the characters to a conclusion.

In conclusion, Koontz sounds like he has something close to publishable, but is restricted by publishing rights, and may have to release a standalone Chris Snow book that concludes the story.